# Grafana and Graphite: applyByNode missing?

Tags: graphite, grafana

I have 2 data series in grafana with Grahite and I want to calculate the ratio of the `first_series/second_series`.

However, the `divideSeries(#A,#B)` function accepts only a single series while I have a list of series #A and #B.

What  I would like to do is divideSeries after grouping it by a particular node or wildcard.
In the graphite documentation I see a `applyByNode` function but the documentation is pretty unclear and it is not present in Grafana. Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to archive this, or if it is not possible?

**Further Detail About the Series **

I have a list of items by subcategory of this nature:

```
xx.A.cat1   
xx.A.cat2  
xx.A.cat3  
xx.A.cat4
```

... and so on.

and I have another list

```
xx.total.cat1  
xx.total.cat2  
xx.total.cat3
```

... and so on.

I want to calculte a sort of average of the two corresponding series by 
xx.A.* / xx.total.* i.e.

```
xx.A.cat1/xx.total.cat1
xx.A.cat2/xx.total.cat2
```

Comment: Which version of graphite are you using? 0.9.x doesn't support applyByNode anyway.

Also, can you provide an example of the series you have?  Are they something like x.y.A, x.y.B, c.d.A & c.d.B where you want a set of series in your output like A = x.y.A / c.d.A & B = x.y.B / c.d.B ?

Comment: @AussieDan I have added mroe explaination about what I am trying to archieve

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  What version of graphite are you using?

Comment: @AussieDan I think it is 0.9.x, not sure exactly which one, and yes, applyByNode is not supported in it.

Answer (score 2):

With Graphite 0.9.x the only option I'm aware of would be to use the repeat panel option in Grafana to create a separate graph for each series.  That will give you the data you're looking for, but with each category on a separate graph.

To do that you'd create a template variable `$category` use the Query type and enter `xx.A.*` as the query string, enabling the 'Include all option' checkbox.

Then you can create a graph panel with a query like `divideSeries(xx.A.$category, xx.total.$category)` and on the General tab under Templating select category for the Repeat Panel option.  You'll also want to set the Title to $category.

Save the dashboard and refresh, and you'll have a graph panel for each category showing the values you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will try that. Do you know of any tools that can help plot non-time series data with Graphite?